# nlog can't find console target

Tags: c#, nlog

I am trying to log to the console via nlog and am getting an exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer fo
r 'MyApp' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationEr
rorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for
nlog: Exception occurred when loading configuration from C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe.config (C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe.config line 14) --->
NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Exception occurred when loading configuration f
rom C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe.config ---> System.ArgumentException: T
arget cannot be found: 'Console'
   at NLog.Config.Factory`2.CreateInstance(String name)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseTargetsElement(NLogXmlElement tar
getsElement)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseNLogElement(NLogXmlElement nlogEl
ement, String baseDirectory)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseTopLevel(NLogXmlElement content,
String baseDirectory)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize(XmlReader reader, String fi
leName, Boolean ignoreErrors)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize(XmlReader reader, String fi
leName, Boolean ignoreErrors)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration..ctor(XmlElement element, String fileN
ame)
   at NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler.System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectio
```

Here is my config file:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
    </configSections>

    <nlog>
        <targets>
            <target name="c" type="Console" />
            <!--<target name="logfile" type="File" fileName="log.txt" archiveAboveSize="10240" maxArchiveFiles="-1" />-->
        </targets>
        <rules>
            <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="c" />
        </rules>
    </nlog>
</configuration>
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MyApp");
```

I am compiling with mono with the following command:

```
dmcs -reference:NLog.dll MyApp.cs
```

I am using the latest? version of nlog from [here](http://nlog.codeplex.com/downloads/get/259963), and I have 4.0 of the .Net framework. This app works fine on a Windows 7 Home PC (also .Net 4.0), but seems to throw this exception on my XP pro PC. I can't imagine that would be the difference, but being a .Net dummy I'm at a loss as to what the problem could be.

Has anyone seen this before or have any insights as to what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why (though, I suspect it is a .Net framework versioning issue), but using nlog v1 instead of v2 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

r u use ${counter} or other function needed in NLog layout?